# RuntimeException when Service load in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I try to create a simple service in Symfony 3 (tuto example)

When I run my page, I get this error :

> The autoloader expected class SocialBundle\Services\OCAntispam to be
>   defined in file .. ../src/SocialBundle/Services/OCAntispam.php. The
>   file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo.

I follow strictly the tutorial (in French) Made by Sensio labs

My service code is

```
namespace SocialBundle\Antispam;

class OCAntispam
{
  public function isSpam($text)
  {
    return strlen($text) < 50;
  }
}
```

In my controller

```
 $antispam = $this->container->get('social.antispam');
```

And the services.yml

```
    social.antispam:
        class: SocialBundle\Services\OCAntispam
```

If it's a typo error, I'm blind

Thanks for any support

EDIT :

On my service, I tried this code:

```
namespace SocialBundle\Services\Antispam;
namespace SocialBundle\Services\OCAntispam;
```

Without success

Comment: SocialBundle\Services vs SocialBundle\Antispam Can you spot the difference?

Comment: I changed namespace SocialBundle\Antispam to namespace SocialBundle\Services\Antispam and namespace SocialBundle\Services\OCAntispam The error is still here

Comment: Update your question with the changes.  What you just wrote makes no sense.  I bet if you look closer you will find the error message changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `namespace` in service class as below.

```
namespace SocialBundle\Services;

class OCAntispam
{
  public function isSpam($text)
  {
    return strlen($text) < 50;
  }
}
```

The `namespace` defined in `Class` shouldn't have `Class` name.

And make sure your file `OCAntispam.php` is under `SocialBundle\Services`.

That should work.

Comment: It is that. Thanks